# Создание динамичной страницы в Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Когда пытаюсь зайти на главную страницу, Spring отдаёт

> Whitelabel Error Page There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found,
> status=404).

**Контроллер:**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
private String text = "Some text";

     @RequestMapping("/")
     public String index(Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("text", text);
         return "home";
    }
}
```

**Страница (`resources/templates/home.html`):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href=\"favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style=text-align:center>th:text="'Hello, ' + ${text} + '!'"</h1>
</html>
```

Что я упустил?

Comment: Конфигурацию `dispatcher`-а покажите пожалуйста. Как вариант попробуйте в `RequestMapping` страницы сделать так: `{"", "/"}`. И как вы обращаетесь на эту страницу?

Comment: Конфигурации нету, думаю в этом дело. Где можно почитать про неё? Спасибо.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/336816/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить следующую конфигурацию

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```